# What data quantity is considered as too big for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I am looking for a free SQL database able to handle my data model. The project is a production database working in a local network not connected to the internet without any replication. The number of application connected at the same times would be less than 10.

The data volume forecast for the next 5 years are:

- 3 tables of 100 millions rows
- 2 tables of 500 millions rows
- 20 tables with less than 10k rows

My first idea was to use MySQL, but I have found around the web [several articles](http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/WP-DataStax-MySQLtoCassandra.pdf) saying that MySQL is not designed for big database. But, what is the meaning of **big** in this case?

Is there someone to tell me if MySQL is able to handle my data model?
I read that Postgres would be a good alternative, but require a lot of hours for tuning to be efficient with big tables.

I don't think so that my project would use NOSQL database.
I would know if someone has some experience to share with regarding MySQL.

**UPDATE**

The database will be accessed by C# software (max 10 at the same times) and web application (2-3 at the same times),

It is important to mention that only **few update will be done on the big tables**, only insert query. Delete statements will be only done few times on the 20 small tables.

The big tables are very often used for select statement, but the most often in the way to know if an entry exists, not to return grouped and ordered batch of data.

Comment: It's not just a matter of size, it really depends on the way you expect to access your data and the constraint of your application (selecting, updating, deleting). MySQL can perfectly handle the number of record you mention.

Comment: What you're asking about much depends on hardware and usage scenarios more than what type of software you run. The hardware will decide what the speed of your imagined system would be. Searching or manipulating 50 gigabytes of data using RDBMS or a NoSQL will be equally slow if you need to inspect all of it. Basically, without hardware in place and usage scenarios, you can't really do a proper estimate on what's fine and what isn't. Also, 1 billion rows isn't much, several terabytes of data spanning across several remote locations is.

Comment: @elbuild, I have updated the question with more information regarding the way to access the database and which type of statements will be done

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I work for Percona, a company that provides consulting and other services for MySQL solutions.

For what it's worth, we have worked with [many customers](http://www.percona.com/about-us/customers) who are successful using MySQL with very large databases. Terrabytes of data, tens of thousands of tables, tables with billions of rows, transaction load of tens of thousands of requests per second. You may get some more insight by reading some of our [customer case studies](http://www.percona.com/resources/mysql-case-studies).

You describe the number of tables and the number of rows, but nothing about how you will query these tables. Certainly one could query a table of only a few hundred rows in a way that would not scale well. But this can be said of any database, not just MySQL.

Likewise, one could query a table that is terrabytes in size in an efficient way. It all depends on how you need to query it.

You also have to set specific goals for performance. If you want queries to run in milliseconds, that's challenging but doable with high-end hardware. If it's adequate for your queries to run in a couple of seconds, you can be a lot more relaxed about the scalability.

The point is that MySQL is not a constraining factor in these cases, any more than any other choice of database is a constraining factor.

---

Re your comments.

MySQL has [referential integrity checks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) in its default storage engine, InnoDB. The claim that "MySQL has no integrity checks" is a myth often repeated over the years.

I think you need to stop reading superficial or outdated articles about MySQL, and read some more complete and current documentation.

- [MySQLPerformanceBlog.com](http://mysqlperformanceblog.com/)
- [High Performance MySQL, 3rd edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do)
- [MySQL 5.6 manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I am glad to read that MySQL is able to manage this quantity of data. I read also some comment on the internet saying that MySQL has no DB integrity check. It is because some people doesn't suggest to use MySQL for production DB. Seems weird, what do you think about that?

Comment: Also, I have updated the question with more details regarding the way I need to access the database.

Comment: I have to use existing IT infrastructure of my company. The OS of the server will be Windows Server 2008. Could it be a problem for MySQL?

Comment: Only about [6% of respondants](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/11/30/what-operating-system-do-you-run-mysql-on-in-production/) said they use Windows in production for MySQL. MySQL works fine on Windows, but most people use Linux, probably for cultural reasons as much as technical reasons. If you can't choose the server OS, then the question doesn't matter much. Any other database will suffer on Windows as much as MySQL does.

Comment: I'm amazed at how often people read articles from 2002 and don't bother to check that they're still relevant. Though it doesn't help that there are a few bad, outdated and wrong articles around that don't bother mentioning version numbers. I'm a happy Pg user and dev, but get really annoyed when people say they want to use Pg because "it has foreign keys and RI constraints". Seriously, please join us in this decade.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL has a two important (and significantly different) database engines - MyISAM and InnoDB. A limits depends on usage - MyISAM is nontransactional - there is relative fast import, but it is too simple (without own memory cache) and JOINs on tables higher than 100MB can be slow (due too simple MySQL planner - hash joins is supported from 5.6). InnoDB is transactional and is very fast on operations based on primary key - but import is slower.

Current versions of MySQL has not good planner as Postgres has (there is progress) - so complex queries are usually much better on PostgreSQL - and really simple queries are better on MySQL.

Complexity of PostgreSQL configuration is myth. It is much more simple than MySQL InnoDB configuration - you have to set only five parameters: max_connection, shared_buffers, work_mem, maintenance_work_mem and effective_cache_size. Almost all is related to available memory for Postgres on server. Usually work for 5 minutes. On my experience a databases to 100GB is usually without any problems on Postgres (probably on MySQL too). There are two important factors - how speed you expect and how much memory and how fast IO you have.

With large databases you have to have a experience and knowledges for any database technology. All is fast when you are in memory, and when ratio database size/memory is higher, then much more work you have to do to get good results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very useful information. I won't use MyISAM engine because almost all the fields of my big tables are foreign key.

Comment: I spent years working with Oracle, before switching to MySQL. Now I work with PostgreSQL. I can assure you that PostgreSQL is not complicated compared to others. It is just that PostgreSQL is more secure with its default settings, so you have to make a couple of changes to postgresql.conf and pg_hba before you can connect to it from remote servers. Similarly, the default settings in PostgreSQL (buffers) used to be low. Now that has been changed. If you anticipate the need to write complex queries (WITH clause, recursion etc), PostgreSQL may be better. Straight off the bat, MySQL may be faster.

Comment: @Jayadevan Thanks for your comment. Experiences from developer are always very useful.

Comment: Please also consider the data types you might need. In case of date/time , MySQL added microsecond precision recently. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html . IP data types are still not there whereas they have been there is PostgreSQL for a long time .http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-net-types.html. All these issues gave me a tough time while working with device data that had to be captured with millisecond precision.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, MySQLs table size is only limited by the allowed file size limit of your OS which is I. The terra bytes on any modern OS. That would pose no problems. Most important are questions like this:

1. What kind of queries will you run?
2. Are the large table records updated frequently or basically archives for history data?
3. What is your hardware budget?
4. What is the kind of query speed you need?
5. Are you familiar with table partitioning, archive tables, config tuning?
6. How fast do you need to write (expected inserts per second)
7. What language will you use to connect to the db (Java, .net, Ruby etc)
8. What platform are you most familiar with?
9. Will you run queries which might cause table scans such like '%something%' which would have to go through every single row and take forever

MySQL is used by Facebook, google, twitter and others with large tables and 100,000,000 is not much in the age of social media. MySQL has very little drawbacks (even though I prefer postgresql in most cases) like altering large tables by adding a new index for example. That might send your company in a couple days forced vacation if you don't have a replica in the meantime. Is there a reason why NoSQL is not an option? Sometimes hybrid approaches are a good choice like having your relational business logic in MySQL and huge statistical tables in a NoSQL database like MongoDb which can scale by adding new servers in minutes (MySQL can too but it's more complicated). Now MongoDB can have a indexed column which can be searched by in blistering speed.
Bejond the bottom line: you need to answer the above questions first to make a very informed decision. If you have huge tables and only search on indexed keys almost any database will do - if you expect many changes to the structure down the road you want to use a different approach.

Edit:
Based on your update you just posted I doubt you would run into problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer full of real question to think about. I have never thought about an hybrid database. Could be a possibility.

Comment: If you are using C# all it takes is another data context and connection string and you are good to go and can grow your tables to billions of records. I am using this approach to store JSON twitter documents as they are a perfect fit for MongoDB which stores bson(binary Json).